# Extracting an array into dynamic variables

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I am trying to be lazy (or smart): I have 7 checkboxes which correlate with 7 columns in a MySQL table.

The checkboxes are posted in an array:

```
$can = $_POST['can'];
```

I've created the following loop to dump the variables for the MySQL insert:

```
for($i=1;$i<8;$i++){
    if($can[$i] == "on"){
        ${"jto_can".$i} = 'Y';
    }
    else{
        ${"jto_can".$i} = 'N';
    }
}
print_r($jto_can1.$jto_can2.$jto_can3.$jto_can4.$jto_can5.$jto_can6.$jto_can7);
```

This correctly outputs:

```
YYNYYYY
```

However, when I attempt to use those variables in my MySQL update, it doesn't accept the changes.

```
mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE jto SET jto_can1 = '$jto_can1', jto_can2 = '$jto_can2', jto_can3 = '$jto_can3', jto_can4 = '$jto_can4', jto_can5 = '$jto_can5', jto_can6 = '$jto_can6', jto_can7 = '$jto_can7' WHERE jto_id = '$id'")or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

Can anyone explain why the print_r displays the variables whereas MySQL update does not?

Comment: Stick with the array, there's no point or benefit in creating all of those variables.

Comment: Also, you're missing a space in between the "WHERE" here: `jto_can7 = '$jto_can7'WHERE jto_id = '$id'`

Comment: How should I go about loading the array into MySQL then?

Comment: What data type is the columns in your table?

Comment: @hank, they are ENUM columns - set for Y and N

Comment: You'd be better off making your update statement in the loop you have, and appending the values to the end. Have an array of the column names, and then those values, and going from there.

Comment: what is the error message ...

Comment: In making your `dynamic` variables... you are making your mysql statement `not so dynamic` since you will have to change the max count in your for loop, and append or remove vars from your mysql if the fields change. Just use the array.

Comment: Kindly echo the query as echo "UPDATE jto SET jto_can1 = '$jto_can1', jto_can2 ......." to know the error

Comment: @Vineet1982, it doesn't output an error - which is what was making me believe it's not a SQL issue per se.

Comment: @thebarless can you echo the query to know what is printing...

Comment: @Vineet1982 - well, that solved that. I lost my ID variable along the lines. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick with the array, and form the query dynamically:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE jto SET ';

$cols = array();
foreach( range( 1, 7) as $i) {
    $value = $_POST['can'][$i] == 'on' ? 'Y' : 'N'; // Error check here, $_POST['can'] might not exist or be an array
    $cols[] = 'jto_can' . $i . ' = "' . $value . '"'; 
}

$sql .= implode( ', ', $cols) . ' WHERE jto_id = "' . $id . '"';
```

Now do a `var_dump( $sql);` to see your new SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

this is not a mysql problem. mysql will only see what you put into that string. e.g. dump out the query string BEFORE you do mysql_query. I'm guessing you're doing this query somewhere else and have run into scoping problems. And yes, this is lazy. No it's not "smart". you're just making MORE work for yourself. What's wrong with doing

```
INSERT ... VALUES jto_can1=$can[0], jto_can2=$can[1], etc...
```

Comment: The only difficulty I have with this method is that I'm not seeing how to control that $can[0] get's a "N" value when the box is unchecked. The array will only pass the checked ones (unless I'm missing something).